# password encryption joomla and jomsocial

Tags: joomla, authentication, registration, jomsocial

We have a weird problem with password encryption at our website beta1.iamyogi.com.

1. We register a user at the website. There is a full registration possible with activation link in the e-mail. It is working till I want to log in. Even with a simple user "John" and password "12345".
2. If I change the password for "John" in the CMS to "12345" and save
   the user account, I can login on the front with John/12345.
3. If I look at the database, the only change there is it the password field xxxx_users. First it was something like:

   - `ad2630323c070b40776acc011b5c5116` then after the CMS change of password:
   - `$P$DXe2T/Ceh3PeRAxdsFdwfYhKEndxIg`.

It looks way different in type of encryption.

Do you know how this is possible?!

Joomla 3.2.1 and joomla 3.2.2 joomla 3.2.3, all tested same problem
jomsocial 3.1

Comment: Please contact the developer of JomSocial as it's a commercial extension and therefore you will most likely no get an answer

Comment: The newer Joomla has switched to stronger password encryption. This is seamless unless you are using another plugin and have to make some adjustment.

Comment: Do you know where to make an adjustment?